# High PPI 2.2 inch TFT Display shield for Raspberry pi 2B/B+ With 6 Keyboards and Remote IR

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, display

I have the following display "High PPI 2.2 inch TFT Display shield for Raspberry pi 2B/B+ With 6 Keyboards and Remote IR" (built in in case):
[image]
Some pictures and instructions can be found [here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1dDhhcA1#path=%252F2.2%2520inch%2520TFT%2520for%2520RPI).

So once connected it just white and not shows anything. I tried to follow these instructions/steps:

1. Download the official firmware, then upgrade to the latest kernel
   `sudo rpi-update`
2. Installation gpio libraries and drivers:

`sudo apt-get install gcc python-pygame python-dev`

`sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/R/RPi.GPIO/RPi.GPIO-0.5.11.tar.gz`

`sudo tar zxvf RPi.GPIO-0.5.11.tar.gz`

`cd RPi.GPIO-0.5.11`

`sudo python setup.py install`

3. Config file to enable I2C and SPI Interface
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt

Add the following line: `dtparam=i2c_arm=on, spi=on`

4. Config modules to startup screen.

`sudo nano /etc/modules`

Add the following line: `fbtft_device name=pitft rotate=270 speed=48000000 fps=30`

5. Config cmdline file to display the console;

`sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt`

Add the following line before “rootwait”

`fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8`

6. Save then restart;

But it still does not work. Any advice what I'm missing? Easiest way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find [easy](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-2-pitft-hat-320-240-primary-display-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install) and [detailed steps](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-2-pitft-hat-320-240-primary-display-for-raspberry-pi/detailed-installation) for installing software required to make it work at Adafruit site.

Steps are the following (easy option):

1. Download and install kernel and helper script:

   `curl -SLs https://apt.adafruit.com/add-pin | sudo bash`
   `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-bootloader`
   `sudo apt-get install adafruit-pitft-helper`
2. Run helper script:

   `sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t 22`
3. Reboot by issuing `sudo reboot`

Note: It seems that there is no way to make this TFT work simultaneously with external monitor connected over HDMI.